# I want to check if both of text field is not empty then go to next page

Tags: flutter, if-statement

I am creating an app where you should register to go to the next page. I want to check if both of text field is not empty then go to next page

```
if (nameController.text.isEmpty) {
                    _validateName = true;
                  } else {
                    _validateName = false;
                  }
                  if (jobController.text.isEmpty) {
                    _validateJob = true;
                  } else {
                    _validateJob = false;
                  }
```

I want to check if these two are false then go to the next page

```
                  if (_validateJob == false || _validateName == false) {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return GetUser();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
_validateName = nameController.text.isNotEmpty;
_validateJob = jobController.text.isNotEmpty
```

```dart
if (_validateName && _validateJob) {
 // Navigator code ...
}
```